# How do I create an automation program that can run NMAP on my network weekly?

Tags: security, networking, automation, nmap

So I know nothing about programming whatsoever. But I'm still open minded and I want to know what would be the steps to create an automation program to run NMAP on my machine weekly and having it send the results to my e-mail without me even touching the software.

Is it easy enough for someone like me to research some programming codes and create this automation program, or is it complex?

Answer (score 0):

Run it as a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job on a Linux machine.

```
# crontab -l
```

This will start an editor, add there

```
MAILTO="you@example.com"
10 15 * * 0 nmap (command parameters there)
```

Your nmap will run every Sunday at 15:10.